# php class variable is not updating

Tags: php, oop

```
Connect.php
class Connect{
    private static $_INSTNC = null;
    private $_SSN='no_session';
    private function __construct(){
        try{
//database connection
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static function getInstnc(){
        if(!isset(self::$_INSTNC)){
            self::$_INSTNC = new Connect();
        }
        return self::$_INSTNC;
    }
    public function setSsn($param){
        $this->_SSN = $param;
        return $this->_SSN;
    }
    public function chkSsn(){
        echo $this->_SSN;

    }
}
```

Here I am setting Session in login page after successfully validation.

```
login.php

Connect::getInstnc()->setSsn('admin');
```

But it prints default value 'no_session' while accessing from another page. As session already set, it has to change default value. The value of `$_SSN` is not updating.

```
dash.php
echo Connect::getInstnc()->chkSsn();
```

Comment: It seems to work correctly as far as I can see: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8551af409e1df7148544fbf766a13d78fe83aa2 Presumably there is some detail you have not mentioned. Perhaps you are executing those two lines in two different requests, or something?

Comment: Make sure you call these methods in __one__ request.

Comment: Yeah I am setting session from login page and accessing session from dash page. How can I do ?

Comment: [The web is stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680380/meaning-of-web-is-stateless-and-http-is-statless-protocol); you need to propagate the state of the session from request to request (normally by storing the session id in a cookie).

Comment: Variables are not kept in between requests. If you want the variables to be kept between requests you must store them somewhere, perhaps in $_SESSION, or in a database, or file, or any other form of persistent storage.